# How to have multiple font sizes in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jeditorpane

I am trying to make my own version of NotePad, however, I cannot figure out how to have different font sizes in the same `JEditorPane`.

```
jEditorPane1.setFont(jEditorPane1.getFont().deriveFont(font));
```

The code above I have changes all text to one font size in a editor pane. But I would like to make it so I can have more than one font size.

Comment: Here are some examples to set the editor fonts (different fonts within the same document) at the Oracle's Java swing tutorials on [How to use Editor and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html). Also, try searching the web for similar examples and browsing the API for more ideas.

Comment: Don't use a JEditorPane. A JEditor pane is used to display HTML. Use a JTextPane, it is used to display text. I would look at [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html). It provides a basic example that does what you want.